# extract lines from text files with column value equal to pattern

Tags: bash

The files have an identical header, consisting of many columns, and only one row.  First, I have extracted the header and saved it to newA.txt and newB.txt.  Next, I need to extract from each file, the lines where column 21 matches the pattern A00[1-9], the lines where column 21 matches the pattern B00[1-9], and not include the lines where column 21 matches the pattern A00[1-9]_B00[1-9].  The lines are appended to their respective text file: A patterns appended to newA.txt, and B patterns appended to newB.txt.  Note that the number of rows matching the patterns are unknown, the last number of the pattern varies between 1-9, and there may not be any rows after the header in some of the text files.

The example below is what I have worked out so far, but is obviously not what I'm looking for.  This will only print out the column values for A patterns, not including the header.

```
FILES=exp.var1.*.cat.out
for f in $FILES; do
    cat $f | tail -n +2 | awk '$21 ~ /^A00[0-9]/ { print $21 }'
done
```

This prints something like:

```
A001
A001_B001
```

The text files have columns that are tabular delimited, and the number of rows may only equal 1 (the header only), or may equal many (header plus 1 or more A or B patterns and also A*_B* patterns).

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work

```
$ awk '$21 ~ /^A00[1-9]_B00[1-9]/ {next}
       $21 ~ /^A00[1-9]/          {print > "newA.txt"}
       $21 ~ /^B00[1-9]/          {print > "newB.txt"}' exp.var1.*.cat.out
```

will skip the lines where combined pattern matches, otherwise send the matching lines to corresponding files.  There is no need for looping over files.

Or, easier to extend to other chars with the following (not sure if there is a usecase or not?)

```
$ awk '$21 ~ /^A00[1-9]_B00[1-9]/ {next}
       $21 ~ /^[AB]00[1-9]/ {print > ("new" substr($21,1,1) ".txt")}' exp.var1.*.cat.out
```

If there is a chance that the header might match, you can add `FNR==1 ||` to the first condition where we skip the line.

Obviously not tested....

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change your regular expression to `/^[AB]00[0-9]$/` to get the desired match.

Comment: This does remove the pattern I don't want.  Now my question is how to extract the lines for each A and B pattern, and append those lines to the pattern text files containing the header, while keeping in mind there could be varying numbers of A or B pattern lines.